# Is there a way to print twice but sleep in between each print calls but have both print on the same line?

Tags: perl

I really don't know how to word this question, so I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a script where I need to use the sleep function for a few seconds. But before I go to "sleep" I need to have a message say for example "Sleeping... ". But after it's done sleeping, I need to print "done". So what the terminal window will look like would be something like this: `Sleeping... done`, and this is my code for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Sleeping... ";
sleep(1);
print "done";
```

But what happens is, the script sleeps, and it then outputs `Sleeping... done` all at once.

Is it possible to print "Sleeping... ", then actually go to "sleep", and finally print "done", but have everything on one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable auto flush on the file handle by setting `$|` to a non-zero value, such as:

```
local $| = 1;
```

So you're full script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $| = 1;

print "Sleeping... ";
sleep(1);
print "done";
```

You can turn it back off by setting `$|` to `0`, which you should do if this is just a small part of a larger script.  Output is buffered by default for a reason.

Comment: It should also be noted that `sleep` is quite imprecise, with an error of +- 1sec. The [`Time::HiRes` module](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Time-HiRes-1.9725/HiRes.pm) can help if higher precision is neccessary.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response. But thanks, it worked. Any reason why you used local?

Comment: Habit I guess.  It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$| = 1
```

to disable buffered output. Then your script works as expected.

Comment: Far better, and more readable in modern code, is to use the form `STDOUT->autoflush(1)`, rather than relying on the global punctuation vars.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

```
select()->autoflush();   # Same as:  $| = 1;
print "Sleeping... ";
sleep(1);
print "done\n";

print "Sleeping... ";
select()->flush();       # Same as:  my $saved = $|; $| = 1; $| = $saved;
sleep(1);
print "done\n";
```

(You can replace `select()` with `STDOUT` if you don't otherwise use `select()`.)